# Momentum update rule in Adam optimizer

Tags: optimization, deep-learning, neural-network, gradient-descent

In momentum update for Adam rule,

Mt= ß(Mt-1) + (1-ß)grad(theta)
(ß=0.9-->usually)
why do we multiply the gradient with (1-beta)?
I mean the whole idea of momentum based gradient descent was to move a bit more ahead/backward than what our gradient tells us. But in this case we are not even moving as much as the gradient tells us to.

Can someone explain why this happens?